# How does this code know to return the length of the longest word in the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This is my code:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    var p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length > p){
            p = arr[i].length;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I know it works, but I am unsure why it is able to pick out only the longest word of the string. I understand that the sting gets split into an array, and the for loop checks the length of each string in the array, but how does `p=arr[i].length` ALWAYS pick the longest one to return?

Comment: Think about what the `if` statement before that assignment to `p` means.

Comment: What do you understand from this `if (arr[i].length > p){`? It says *when the length of the current word is longer than the current maximum length, update the maximum length because you found a longer word*.\

Comment: It is incremental. The first time `p = arr[i].length` is executed, it most probably will not be the longest one yet, but as the other words are compared with that length, any longer length gets assigned to `p` via that same assignment, and again, and again. At the end, one can be sure it represents the largest word.

Comment: The if statement could also be `p = Math.max(p, arr[i].length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begin p is equal to 0

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //loop all words in array

if (arr[i].length > p){

only if p (the length of previous word) is longer than current

p = arr[i].length; //I update p with the current length (not always, but according to if statement)

So at end of loop p is equal to the length of longest word.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = str.split(" ");
```

splits the string into an array of words.

`P` holds the maximum length found so far.

We iterate though the array of words and if a word is longer then `p` we assign it's length to `p`

Answer (score 0):

Well It's pretty easy : 
First you take the length of the first word (arr[0].length) and store the value in p.

Then you take the second one which is arr[1].length and compare it with the length of the first one which is stored in p. If the second word is bigger than the first (arr[1] > p) then p becomes array[1], etc.